# lxml: Force to convert newlines to entities

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Is there a way to output newlines inside text elements as `&#13;` entities?
Currently, newlines are inserted into output as-is:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import E
etree.tostring(E.a('one\ntwo'), pretty_print=True)
b'<a>one\ntwo</a>\n'
```

Desired output:

```
b'<a>one&#13;two</a>\n'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to convert newlines to HTML entities?

Comment: @supersam654 a specific application (Premiere Pro / FCPXML format) ignores "plain" newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking through the [lxml docs](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring), it looks like there is no way to force certain characters to be printed as escaped entities. It also looks like the list of characters that gets escaped varies by the output encoding.

With all of that said, I'd use [BeautifulSoup's `prettify()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing) on top of `lxml` to get the job done:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape

def extra_entities(s):
    return escape(s).replace('\n', '&#13;')

soup = Soup("<a>one\ntwo</a>", 'lxml-xml')
print(soup.prettify(formatter=extra_entities))
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a>
 one&#10;two
</a>
```

Note that newlines should actually map to `&#10;` (`&#13;` is for carriage returns or `\r`) but I won't argue because I can't test FCPXML format locally.

Comment: This works in this case, but does not preserve xmlns attributes (lxml-xml parser) or lettercase (lxml parser). My use case (Excel 2002 XML (don't ask)) requires both of those as well as explicit &#10; for newlines...